# CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH  Error :"Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу"

Tags: sql-server, sql

Всем привет. 
Просьба помочь.

Созадал БД:

```
CREATE DATABASE NorthPole ON PRIMARY (

  NAME = NorthPoleDB,

  FILENAME = 'D:\NorthPoleDB.mdf'
)
```

Создал там таблицу и записал туда данные:

```
use NorthPole;
CREATE TABLE pol(id int);
INSERT INTO pol VALUES(1),(6),(5);
SELECT * FROM pol;
```

Теперь, допустим, мне нужно создать новую БД, скопировав существующую (без варианта перейменовки).

```
use current_db
CREATE DATABASE SomeDB
ON (FILENAME = 'D:\NorthPoleDB.mdf')
FOR ATTACH
```

Ошибка

**Сообщение 5120, уровень 16, состояние 101, строка 20

Не удалось открыть физический файл "D:\NorthPoleDB.mdf". Ошибка операционной системы 32: "32(Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл занят другим процессом.)".**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вы собираетесь присоединить файл к другой базе данных, если он уже используется в текущей?

Вы бы его хотя бы скопировали...

А вообще, прочитайте статью с описанием различных вариантов копирования БД: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189624.aspx

Comment: use current_db  я ведь сменил БД.

Comment: Вы сменили базу, в контексте которой выполняется текущий запрос. База при этом осталась подключена к серверу - в любой момент вы можете снова выполнить запрос в контексте этой базы. Отключается база от сервера только явно - через удаление - DROP DATABASE (при этом удаляются и файлы базы) или через отключение - sp_detach_db (при этом файлы остаются на месте).

Comment: Добавил строку EXEC sp_detach_db 'NorthPole', 'true'  .Ошибка осталась

Comment: Проверьте в Management Studio - отключилась ли база, удалилась ли из списка баз, подключенных к серверу. Если да - попробуйте еще раз присоединить файл.